# how to do batch insert/update with Springboot data JPA and Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement batch insert/update records with SpringBoot Data Jpa with Mysql,
here is my yml config:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

And I use an mysql auto increment column as primary key, here

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

I've googled that batch ops will not work with GenerationType.IDENTITY,
but also I notice that mysql not support GenerationType.SEQUENCE
then how could I accomplish bath insert/update with jpa's saveAll(data)  method with mysql DB

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I've googled that batch ops will not work with GenerationType.IDENTITY, but also I notice that mysql not support GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Set the id in the application. For example using a `UUID`

Comment: for some reason I prefer using db auto increment primary key(GenerationType.IDENTITY)   and not uuid . is any workaround ?